# ParentKey not found Error in Model with 2 Foreign Keys

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following models;

//A

```
class A {
   @Id
   private int id;
   @Id
   @Column(name = "D",
        nullable = false,
        precision = 20,
        scale = 0
   )
   private Long dId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JsonManagedReference
   @JoinColumn(
        name = "D",
        nullable = false,
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false
)
   private D d;

   @OneToMany(mappedby = "a",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true )
   Set<C> Cs;
}
```

//B

```
class B {
   @Id
   int id;
  @Column(name = "D",
        nullable = false,
        precision = 20,
        scale = 0
  )
   private Long dId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JsonManagedReference
   @JoinColumn(
        name = "D",
        nullable = false,
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false
)
   private D d;

   @OneToMany(mappedby = "b",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true )
   Set<C> Cs;
}
```

//C

```
class C {
   @Id
   int id;
   String name;
   @ManyToOne
   @JsonManagedReference
   @JoinColumns(

        {
                @JoinColumn(name = "A", insertable = false, updatable = false),
                @JoinColumn(name = "D", insertable = false, updatable = false)

        }
)
private A a;

@ManyToOne
@JsonManagedReference
@JoinColumns(
        {

                @JoinColumn(name = "B", insertable = false, updatable = false),
               @JoinColumn(name = "D", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        }
)
private B B;


@Id
@Column(name = "D",
        nullable = false,
        precision = 20,
        scale = 0)
private Long dId;

@Id
@Column(name = "B",
        nullable = false,
        precision = 3,
        scale = 0)
private Integer bId;

@Id
@Column(name = "A",
       nullable = false,
        precision = 5,
        scale = 0)
private Integer aId;
}
```

//D

```
 class D{
   @Id
   int id;

   @OneToMany(mappedby = "d",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true )
   Set<A> As;
  @OneToMany(mappedby = "d",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true )
   Set<B> Bs;
}
```

So here everything is persisted through by the `class D`. (That means I set the model and save by D repository.)I can save a list of objects `A and B` through `D` without any problem.(without adding C objects). I add objects `C` through the Object `A` as the real relationship of `C` is with the `A`.The problem is when I add an `Object C` by `Object A` spring throws following exception;

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (XYZ.RELATIONSHIP0123) violated - parent key not found

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3897)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
        ... 98 more
```

I found that spring is saving `A` objects first then move to `C` objects before saving `B` objects, so spring throwing above error as there is no entry of `Object B` when `C` objects are saving. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

PS: I dont have any permission to change the DB structure

PSS: This is the table structure of C;

```
PK compositekey(A+B+C)
FK A (number)
FK B (number)
FK D (number)
   lasteditedTime (time)
```

So I'm manually adding the `A, B` and `D`s ids to `C object` and setting each objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your mappings are incorrect.

You need to place the `@Id` directly on the relationship:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships

So the case of A:

```
class A {
   @Id
   private int id;

   //@Id
   //@Column(name = "D")
   //private Long dId;

   @Id //added
   @ManyToOne
   @JsonManagedReference
   @JoinColumn(
        name = "D",
        nullable = false,
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false
   )
   private D d;

   @OneToMany(mappedby = "a",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true )
   Set<C> Cs;
}
```

You need to make a similar change in C for the relationship with B. **Without these changes Hibernate has no idea that A depends on D and C depends on B for the identities.**

You would also typically to create an Id or EmbeddedID class however Hibernate allows multiple ID fields without this.

If you wanted to retain the `dId` field you could use `@MapsId`. I think this would look like the below.

```
class A {
   @Id
   private int id;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "D")
   private Long dId;

   @MapsId("dId") //added
   @ManyToOne
   @JsonManagedReference
   @JoinColumn(
        name = "D",
        nullable = false,
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false
   )
   private D d;

   @OneToMany(mappedby = "a",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true )
   Set<C> Cs;
}
```

Comment: hi, I forgot to add some `@column` markers. can you check it again, thanks for reply

Comment: As I said in the above, the problem only occurs when I add a `C Object` through `B`, otherwise, there is no problem when saving a list of `A`s and `B`s through `D`

Comment: *I forgot to add some @column markers. can you check it again, thanks*. maybe you should take time to ensure your question is correct in the first place.  As I said, your mappings are incorrect.

Comment: hi, i check the code, everything is okay in the code now. i cant change the DB as its already using one based on PK n FK. Spring is inserting A then B. So if there is C , A->C and throws error

Comment: Maybe if you went to the trouble of (a) asking properly in the first place and (b) formatting the posted code correctly you might get more answers.

Comment: Noted, I will do like that in next Qs. thanks for the reply :)

Comment: You need to make the same change in C i.e. add `@Id` to the B relationship and remove the extraneous `bId` property.

Comment: It wont work because in DB table of `C`, there are those id columns..We set id through them

Comment: Sorry, if you won't listen (same as was the case for your previous question) then I can't help you any more.

Comment: I did what you said, it wont add any entry to the C table, now trying your 2nd answer.